# Chrome extension injection blocked by sandbox CSP

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I am currently working on a Chrome extension which has a script that needs to access global properties of the page. To do so, I came up with an approach very similar to *Method 1* in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879), the only difference being that instead of inserting a new `script` element directly in the document, the extension creates an `ìframe` with a `src` attribute pointing to a HTML document that already contains such a `script` tag. This approach is convenient in my use case as this newly created iframe and HTML document are also used for other purposes, but this is not relevant to the minimal reproducible example showcased here.

Here's the code responsible for creating the iframe, executed via a content script **content.js**:

```
const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("src", chrome.runtime.getURL("inject.html"));
document.body.insertBefore(iframe, document.body.firstChild);
```

Here is a simplified version of **inject.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script src="inject.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is **inject.js** (which in reality contains code accessing the global properties of the page):

```
console.log("Loaded!");
```

Finally, **manifest.json** sets both **inject.js** and **inject.html** as web accessible resources and injects **content.js** in all pages:

```
{
    "name": "Example",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Pyves",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "all_frames": true,
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "inject.html",
        "inject.js"
    ],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

The extension is in particular targeting GitHub raw pages (for instance https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PyvesB/JavAssembly/master/README.md), which happen to have a `sandbox` Content Security Policy. So far this setup has been working like a charm, however since updating my Chromium-based browsers from version 63 to 64 earlier this month, the extension is no longer fully functional. **inject.js** is blocked, with the following error message in the browser's console:

> Blocked script execution in 'chrome-extension://xxxx/inject.html' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.

Am I missing something here? How can I once again inject extension scripts in sandboxed frames in Chromium 64+?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me so I've reported it in https://crbug.com/816121

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, I've starred the bug as well! There seem to be quite a lot of opened reports related to extensions and CSP, I do hope that this one gets tackled or that someone can suggest a workaround in the meantime!

Comment: An obvious, but somewhat complicated, workaround would be to modify DOM of the page itself instead of using an iframe. You can also use webRequest API to overwrite the CSP header.

Comment: @wOxxOm By modifying the DOM of the page itself, do you mean inserting the script tags directly for instance? I have attempted that at some point as well, but it was also being blocked because of the sandbox CSP. You're right, overwriting the CPS headers would probably work, but it doesn't seem like the "right" way to solve the problem.

Comment: Well, I don't know what your iframe does, but if it shows a UI of some kind, you can do it in the page itself with more hassle to isolate the styles. There's no need to insert script elements unless you need to run something in the page context.